Tried to get SFML to work but now I can't run any other C++ files in the project folder cause of an error with cl.exe
Now whenever i press the run button on any of my cpp projects not just the sfml project  that I'm talking about, it gives me the error cl.exe build and debug is only usable when VS Code is run from the Developer Command Prompt for VS.
But my project is supposed to be for gcc not for the developer command prompt for VS. And when I do ctrl+shift+b I get:

'cl.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command.

This is the code in my code file, and this is the actual cpp code file with the code:
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode({200, 200}), "SFML works!");
    sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        while (const std::optional event = window.pollEvent())
        {
            if (event->is<sf::Event::Closed>())
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(shape);
        window.display();
    }
}

And if i change it to the code:
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
int main() {
    sf::RenderWindow window(*sf*::VideoMode(800, 600), "Bouncing Ball");
    sf::CircleShape ball(20);
    ball.setFillColor(sf::Color::Red);

    sf::Vector2f velocity(0.3f, 0.3f);

    while (window.isOpen()) {
        sf::Event *event*;
        while (window.pollEvent(*event*)) {
            if (event.*type* == *sf::Event::Closed*) {
                window.close();
            }
        }

        // Move the ball
        ball.move(velocity);

        // Check for collisions with window boundaries
        if (ball.getPosition().x < 0 || ball.getPosition().x + ball.getRadius() * 2 > window.getSize().x) {
            velocity.x = -velocity.x;
        }
        if (ball.getPosition().y < 0 || ball.getPosition().y + ball.getRadius() * 2 > window.getSize().y) {
            velocity.y = -velocity.y;
        }

        window.clear(sf::Color::Black);
        window.draw(ball);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}

There is 5 different red sguiggly lines that starred
And when I put it into an AI it couldn't fix
I followed a tutorial and I downloaded GCC 14.2.0 MinGW (SEH) (UCRT) on https://www.sfml-dev.org/download/sfml/3.0.0/#windows cause I got the gcc from a folder called x86_64-14.2.0-release-posix-seh-ucrt-rt_v12-rev0.
Then i went to c_cpp_properties.json in my .vscode and added the path to my SFML3.0.0/include. And within that folder is a bunch of projects where one of them is my project that uses SFML, and that one has it's own .vscode folder with a tasks.json and launch.json file.
This is my tasks.json file for my sfml project:
    {
      "version": "2.0.0",
      "tasks": [
        {
          "label": "build",
          "type": "shell",
          "command": "g++",
          "args": [
            "-g",
            "${workspaceFolder}/redBallBouncing.cpp",
            "-o",
            "${workspaceFolder}/redBallBouncing",
            "-I",
            "C:\\Users\\This_Is_Where_My_User_Profile_Name_Would_Be\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Libraries\\SFML-3.0.0\\include",
            "-L",
            "C:\\Users\\This_Is_Where_My_User_Profile_Name_Would_Be\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Libraries\\SFML-3.0.0\\lib",
            "-lsfml-graphics",
            "-lsfml-window",
            "-lsfml-system"
          ],
          "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
          },
          "problemMatcher": ["$gcc"]
        }
      ]
    }

And this is the launch.json file for my sfml project:
    {
      "version": "0.2.0",
      "configurations": [
        {
          "name": "Debug",
          "type": "cppdbg",
          "request": "launch",
          "program": "${workspaceFolder}/redBallBouncing",
          "args": [],
          "stopAtEntry": false,
          "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
          "environment": [],
          "externalConsole": false,
          "MIMode": "gdb",
          "setupCommands": [
            {
              "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
              "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
              "ignoreFailures": true
            }
          ],
          "preLaunchTask": "build",
          "miDebuggerPath": "C:/mingw-w64/x86_64-14.2.0-release-posix-seh-ucrt-rt_v12-rev0/mingw64/bin/gdb.exe",
          "logging": {
            "engineLogging": false,
            "trace": false,
            "traceResponse": false
          }
        }
      ]
    }

I also added the path to the SFML lib in my PATH on system variables.

Are you getting error regarding "#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>" from the compiler output, or from VS code editor itself? Also, I am a bit confused on what's the role of Microsoft C++ compiler (cl.exe) here, as you are using MinGW?

My advice is to do what the VSCode instructions tell you and install msys2 and have that install MinGW using pacman and then use the same pacman to install SFML you are making this harder for yourself by doing lots of manual steps: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw My second piece of advice is to disable or remove the code-runner extension when using c++. It only works for the simplest project with 1 source file and no external libraries. Once you have more than that it doesn't handle that.

Ok so I fixed it to the point where the others are fine now and i put my original c_cpp_properties in the .vscode folder of my SFML folder and just opened that folder in vscode on its own but now the #include <SFML/Graphics.hpp> isn't working. So now the hierarchy is Red Ball Bouncing has the folder .vscode and the file redBallBouncing.cpp file. The .vscode folder has the JSON files c_cpp_propertis, tasks, and launch.

ok ill try the pacman thing

Should i take away my original gcc and just restart?
